# Pass Value from First Activity to Third Activity via AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, global-variables

I have an Online Ordering System from where users can complete the order in, at least, three steps. Each step below is a separate activity:

1. Make selection of a Plan
2. Select the Starting Date
3. Select Contents based on selected Plan in Step 1.

Now what I have done in step 1 is, once user clicks on a Plan and Order, below code runs onClick.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SelectDate.class);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();

extras.putString("pass_selected_meal_plan_id",mp_id_pass);
extras.putString("pass_selected_meal_name",mp_name_display);

intent.putExtras(extras);

context.startActivity(intent);

Toast.makeText(context, mp_name_display+" Selected",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

No in the second Activity, I am asking the user to select the order starting date. That is also simple enough and have no issues in it. But the issue begins when I am trying to switch to the third activity.

Since my third activity content is depending on the Plan selection made in the first activity, therefore I have to transfer the selected ID to the third activity. I have it in Extra Bundle in second activity as "pass_selected_meal_plan_id".

The way I am loading the third activity is also crucial. There are two possible ways to start the third activity. First is very simple by putting onClick on the next button. I assume that it will be very simple to transfer the required selection as well. But in this case, as far as I know being a beginner in Android App Development, I will have to give a button to click and load content based on the selected Plan.

The second way is what I want to use. I am running an AsyncTask in the second activity onClick Next. It is working perfectly fine. The only this is I am unable to getExtras in onPostExecute from the previous Activity, i.e. first activity.

I am open to even using Global Variables, but don't really know how to do. Knowing what Global Variables are, I am not too keen to use them instead.

Here is my onPostExecute code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, SelectMeals.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    //Instead of "1" I want the value from previous Activity, which already available in Extras from previous Activity
    extras.putString("pass_selected_meal_plan_id", "1");

    //This is the second value I want to be transferred from first activity to the third activity
    extras.putString("pass_selected_meal_name","Test");

    intent.putExtras(extras);

    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: You said second activity has the id in bundle provided by the first activity. What's holding you back actually? You can't get the id out of bundle?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The problem is that I am unable to get the value in onPostExecute as Extras for the next activity are defined in there. If I transfer it without AsyncTask, it is working perfectly. In other words, the solution of this problem can be by assigning the getExtras from previous activity to puExtras in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code

In your second activity

```
// declare global variables

String id;
String name;
```

Use below code inside `onCreate`

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
 id = bundle.getString("pass_selected_meal_plan_id");  
 name = bundle.getString("pass_selected_meal_name");
```

Now in your Asynctask, write the code below before launching 3rd activity.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, SelectMeals.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();         
    extras.putString("pass_selected_meal_plan_id",id); // first activity data
    extras.putString("pass_selected_meal_name",name); // first activity data
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Finally, you can get these values in third activity.

One important point I would like to highlight is that avoid using generic variable names, e.g. id. It is used just for reference in this answer but it is not a good idea. One obvious problem you may face doing so is with Refactor > Rename. It will change even the @+id in XML files.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have a feeling that this may work. The only thing I need guidance in is how to declare global variables. Actually I am new to it so need guidance. Thank you once again...

Comment: Thank you so much brother. It really helped. I figured out the global variable as well. Really appreciate...